# MongoDB - The argument to $size must be an Array, but was of type: EOO / missing

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, iccube

Trying to create a MongoDB data source with [icCube](http://www.iccube.com). The idea is to return the size of an array as a new field. Something like :

```
$project:
{ 
 "people": 1, 
 "Count myFieldArray" : {$size : "$myFieldArray" }
}
```

But I'm getting for some records the following error :

```
The argument to $size must be an Array, but was of type: EOO
```

Is there a way that size is 0 if the field is empty or not an array (getting rid of the error) ?

Answer (score 161, accepted):

You can use the [**`$ifNull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) operator here. It seems the field is either not an array or not present by the given error:

```js
{ "$project": {
    "people": 1,
    "Count": { 
        "$size": { "$ifNull": [ "$myFieldArray", [] ] }
    }
}}
```

Also you might want to check for the [**`$type`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) in your [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) in case these do exist but are not an array.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works. Strange that $size of an undefined field is not 0 (actually 0 for all no arrays types). I'd expect a nonsql db to be more leniant  (in case a mongo db guy reads this :-) )

Comment: @ic3 Not really, and that is why `$ifNull` exists. The same caveat applies to operators like `$unwind` where you need to be careful that the array is not empty or missing otherwise you will either result in removing the parent document or producing a similar error.

Answer (score 11):

From MongoDB 3.2 and newer, you can use [`$isArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/isArray/) to check if your field is an array along with the [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator to return the field on evaluating with [`$isArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/isArray/):

```
{ "$project": {
    "people": 1,
    "myFieldArrayCount": { 
        "$size": { 
            "$cond": [ 
                { "$isArray": "$myFieldArray" }, 
                "$myFieldArray", 
                []
            ]
        } 
    }
}}
```

Comment: It works, but it's slower than $ifNull

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution would be to eliminate the documents with nulls using

```
$match: {myFieldArray: { $elemMatch: { $exists: true } }}
```

Also, document fields which are used as arguments to $size by '$' reference (here: "$myFieldArray") must also be the part of projections.

```
$project:
{ 
 "people": 1,
 "myFieldArray":1,
 "Count myFieldArray" : {$size : "$myFieldArray" }
}
```