# How to aggregate percentages within arrays?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to work out exactly how to achieve an aggregation, I could manually `unwind` and `group` back together at the end, but I'm sure I should be able to achieve this in a more concise way so I wanted to throw it out as I'm getting stuck.

My document structure (skipping out the un-interesting bits) looks like:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId,
    panels: [
        {
            visConfig: {
                 dataConfig: {
                     columns: [
                         { element: "DX" },
                         { element: "SE" },
                     ]
                 }
            }
        },
        {
            visConfig: {
                 dataConfig: {
                     columns: [
                         { element: "AB" },
                         { element: "XY" },
                     ]
                 }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

What I want to do is calculate a percentage of the `element` overlaps with a given set to be provided. So for example for the document shown it would produce `25%` for the set `["DX"]` or `50%` for the set `["DX", "AB"]`.

So I've tried a few things, I think I've settled on the nearest so far as:

```
$project: {
   _id: 1,
   total: { $sum: { $size: "$panels.visConfig.dataConfig.columns" } }
}
```

But I'm getting an error here which I don't understand:

> The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: missing

Then I'm also having issues with my conditional aggregation which seems to be returning 0 for all of the element values.

```
{
  _id: 1,
  "panels.visConfig.dataConfig.columns.element": { 
      $sum: {
        $cond: [{
          $setIsSubset: [
            ["DX"], ["$panels.visConfig.dataConfig.columns.element"]
          ] 
        }, 1, 0 ],
      }
  },
}
```

Comment: what should be the output from above document?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I'm after something like `{ id: .... , match: 50 }` where `50` is some percentage value ideally.

Comment: Just to note for anyone else coming across this, the error I got with $size is addressed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24201120/mongodb-the-argument-to-size-must-be-an-array-but-was-of-type-eoo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below aggregation in 3.4 version.

```
db.colname.aggregate([
{"$project":{
  "_id":1,
  "total":{
    "$reduce":{
      "input":"$panels.visConfig.dataConfig.columns.element",
      "initialValue":0,
      "in":{"$add":["$$value",{"$size":"$$this"}]}
    }},
    "match":{
      "$sum":{
        "$map":{
          "input":"$panels.visConfig.dataConfig.columns.element",
          "in":{
            "$size":{
              "$setIntersection":[["DX","AB"],"$$this"]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}},
{"$project":{
  "_id":1,
  "percent":{"$multiply":[{"$divide":["$match","$total"]}, 100]}
}}])
```

Update -  You can perform both match and total calculations in $reduce pipeline.

```
db.colname.aggregate([
{"$project":{
  "_id":1,
  "stats":{
    "$reduce":{
      "input":"$panels.visConfig.dataConfig.columns.element",
      "initialValue":{"total":0,"match":0},
      "in":{
        "total":{"$add":["$$value.total",{"$size":"$$this"}]},
        "match":{"$add":["$$value.match",{"$sum":{"$map":{"input":"$$this","in":{"$cond":[{"$in":["$$this", ["DX","AB"]] }, 1, 0]}}}}]}

       }
    }}
}},
{"$project":{
  "_id":1,
  "percent":{"$multiply":[{"$divide":["$stats.match","$stats.total"]}, 100]}
}}])
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at this tomorrow and compare against the other answer. Just reading it though made me wonder, could a `reduce` not also be done on `match` using a condition for the `input`?

Comment: Yw. I've added an update where I've calculated both match and total in the `$reduce` stage without the `$map` part.

Comment: something I've noticed that I'm trying to work out, but maybe you can help is that it doesn't aggregate correctly if the same `columns` array features an element twice. e.g. `columns: [{ element: "DX" }, { element: "DX" }]` for a document will only count them once?

Comment: I didn't account for duplicates and I was processing all the elements under each config at once. Updated answer to process one element at a time i.e changed to use $map to iterate elements and compare against the input array.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to compare the before and after through the edit history to see the change. Then read some documentation to make sure I fully understand how this is working :)

Comment: Makes sense having gone through and documented it all - I feel like in MongoDB there are so many ways of trying to achieve the same thing, can be quite a challenge, especially if you head down the wrong path. I've posted a follow up question if you're interested about performance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51637643/speeding-up-an-aggregation

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) + [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) to get an array of all `element` values and then using [$divide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/divide/index.html) you can divide [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html)-ed [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/index.html) by total [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/index.html):

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            elements: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: { 
                        $map: { 
                            input: "$panels", 
                            as: "panel", 
                            in: "$$panel.visConfig.dataConfig.columns.element" 
                        } 
                    },
                    initialValue: [],
                    in: { $concatArrays: [ "$$this", "$$value" ] }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            percentage: {
                $divide: [ 
                    { 
                        $size: { 
                            $filter: { 
                                input: "$elements", 
                                as: "element", 
                                cond: { 
                                    $in: [ 
                                        "$$element", 
                                        [ "AB", "XY" ] // your input here
                                    ] 
                                } 
                            } 
                        } 
                    },
                    { $size: "$elements" }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm just trying it now, interestingly I'm getting an error `The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: null` possibly because not all my documents have any `panels` or `columns`.

Comment: Additionally, there are a few things in there I'm going to have to go read about! Completely different to the approach I was trying to take, but looks quite promising.

Comment: Yes, you have to filter out all those null values, I guess you don't want any percentages for those docs so you can add $match as first pipeline stage, tried on your data set and looks fine, let me know if you need help with that filtering

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are couple of ways to do this, but I these two pipelines show how I would do it.

```
var values = ["DX", "KL"]
```

- First approach

  ```
  [
     {
        "$project": {
           "percent": {
              "$let": {
                 "vars": {
                    "allsets": {
                       "$reduce": {
                          "input": "$panels.visConfig.dataConfig.columns",
                          "initialValue": [],
                          "in": {
                             "$concatArrays": [ "$$this.element", "$$value" ]
                          }
                       }
                    }
                 },
                 "in": {
                    "$multiply": [
                       {
                          "$divide": [
                             {
                                "$size": {
                                   "$setIntersection": [ "$$allsets", values ]
                                }
                             },
                             { "$size": "$$allsets" }
                          ]
                       },
                       100
                    ]
                 }   
               }
           }
        }
     }
  ]
  ```
- Second approach same idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51618364/3100115) but, using **one** pipeline stage.

  ```
  [
     {
        "$project": {
            "percent": {
              "$multiply": [
                 {
                    "$divide": [
                       {
                          "$sum": {
                             "$map": {
                                "input": "$panels.visConfig.dataConfig.columns.element",
                                "in": {
                                   "$size": {
                                     "$setIntersection": [ values, "$$this" ]
                                   }
                                }
                             }
                          }
                       },
                       {
                          "$reduce": {
                             "input": "$panels.visConfig.dataConfig.columns.element",
                             "initialValue": 0,
                             "in": {
                                "$add": [ "$$value", { "$size": "$$this" } ]
                             }
                          }
                       }
                    ]
                 },
                 100
              ]
           }
        }
     }
  ]
  ```