# How can we query array field with size less than some specific value in mongodb using springboot?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

My objective is to query the array fields who have size less than 5.

I tried the below solution

```
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("Friends");
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("Friend");

        BasicDBObject filter = new BasicDBObject("MainArray", new BasicDBObject("$lt", new BasicDBObject("$size", 4)));
        collection.find(filter).forEach((Consumer<Document>) doc -> {
//perform operations
}
```

I want to fetch the fields whose size is less than 4.

If I directly put the size 4 -- `new BasicDBObject("$size",4)` It did works.

But I want to fetch the fields with array size less than 4 In that case it didn't work.

Please provide your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using annotations.

```
{$expr:{$lt:[{$size:"$MainArray"}, 5]}}
```

You need to use `$expr` to use operators in simple find.

Equivalent in `BasicDBObject` is

```
new BasicDBObject("$expr", 
       new BasicDBObject("$lt", 
            Arrays<DBObject>.asList(new BasicDBObject("$size", "$MainArray"), 5)
       )
)
```

Comment: Hey thanks this looks promising I do remember this works in mongodb ...but it's giving error at Arrays<DBObject>. Have I missed something?
Do we need to import something?
It's giving unexpected token, Expression expected, Cannot resolve DBObject.

Comment: You can use BasicDBObject in place of DBObject

Comment: Now it's showing Expression expected, ')' expected, ;expected at  Arrays<BasicDBObject>

Comment: Please add one extra `)` at the end. Updating the answer

Comment: No problem....although I used the correct braces -- BasicDBObject filter = new BasicDBObject("$expr", new BasicDBObject("$lt", Arrays<BasicDBObject>.asList(new BasicDBObject("$size","$MainArray"),5)));
But it's showing the same error

Comment: Hey @Gibbs 
Strange to see neither did the mongodb query worked. 
It says the argument to $size must be array, but was of type: missing
Although I can clearly see in MongoDb Compass it's an array and even it's mentioned. 
Then I was reading this question -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24201120/mongodb-the-argument-to-size-must-be-an-array-but-was-of-type-eoo-missing
Can you please suggest something

Comment: Same brackets error still? Can you post your updated query?

Comment: Sure...Sorry it's my fault.  I think so I must update the question. Because I the array whose size I want to fetch is a little deeper inside the document. Please check the updated question again. I'm adding a document in json format.
MongoQuery was -- db.collectionName.find({"$expr":{$gte:[{$size:"$Main_Array.address"},2]}})

Comment: Maybe due to fetching the size of the 'address' array we are getting the errors. Do you have any idea how should we modify the query?

Comment: You have modified your entire question. Since you have nested arrays, you need to work on your mongo queries first. I would suggest you to post another question.

Comment: Okay ..sure man understood
Thanks for helping
And sorry for the inconvenience caused. I really appreciate you for helping me.
I will try to edit the question again and will mark your answer as correct.
Thanks